# Open a link in new tab in Safari on macOS Sierra

Tags: safari, macos, shortcut

Before macOS Sierra I could open new link with <kbd>command</kbd>-click in Safari. It doesn't work anymore.  What's the shortcut in macOS Sierra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

⌘-click works fine for me in Safari under macOS sierra 10.12.

Check that **⌘-click opens a link in a new tab** is checked under: Safari > Preferences... > Tabs

If it's checked and not working, uncheck it and close Safari. Then Open Safari and check it. Does it work now?

[image: Safari > Preferences... > Tabs]